# How can I convert a Grammar to NFA?

Tags: automata, finite-automata, regular-expressions, simulation

Hello I have a task where I´m stucking at.

I have to convert a Grammar to NFA. I have these information:

```
G=(V,T,P,S) V={S}, T{0} and 

S -> 0S
S -> 0
```

I can´t do anything with this information for me it´s not clear.
If someone can help it would be very nice.

Comment: This is a grammar. So neither a regex nor a NFA.

Comment: Okey and how can I convert it to NFA ?

Answer (score -1):

The language of the grammar is clearly $0^*0$. Hence just build an NFA for this language (which is very easy to do).

Comment: I´ve made it. Thanks